# How to retry transaction after a deadlock using Doctrine?

Tags: php, mysql, database, doctrine-orm, deadlock

I am writing a PHP function which store/updates large sets of data into a table and that may cause a deadlock. I tried investigating how to retry a failed transaction with Doctrine but sadly could not find any info online. I eventually wrote the following code

```
 $retry = 0;
 $done = false;
 while (!$done and $retry < 3) {
     try {

         $this->entityManager->flush();
         $done = true;

     } catch (\Exception $e) {
         sleep(1);

         $retry++;
     }
 }

 if ($retry == 3) {
     throw new Exception(
         "[Exception: MySQL Deadlock] Too many people accessing the server at the same time. Try again in few minutes"
     );
 }
```

**My question:** is there a chance this approach will insert duplicates in the database? if so, how can I force Doctrine to roll back the transactions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A deadlock returns error 1213 which you should process on the client side

Note that a deadlock and lock wait are different things. In a deadlock, there is no "failed" transaction: they are both guilty. There is no guarantee which one will be rolled back.

You must use `rollback`, your style code will insert duplicate. for example you should :

```
$retry = 0;

$done = false;


$this->entityManager->getConnection()->beginTransaction(); // suspend auto-commit

while (!$done and $retry < 3) {

    try {

        $this->entityManager->flush();

        $this->entityManager->getConnection()->commit(); // commit if succesfull

        $done = true;

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        $this->entityManager->getConnection()->rollback(); // transaction marked for rollback only

        $retry++;

    }

}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you :) This at least gives me an idea of how to proceed.

Comment: Actually, this is no longer true, as in case of Exception `EntityManager` enters closed state and it will throw an `ORMException ` stating that the entity manager is closed on second try. Doctrine version 2.4.*

Comment: this is how to reset entitymanager when closed https://codedump.io/share/rjB45oiwtqwo/1/doctrine2-the-entitymanager-is-closed-how-to-reset-entity-manager-in-symfony2

Comment: Doctrine 2.6.*+ have an `\Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\RetryableException` exception, that catch both `Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DeadlockException` and `Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\LockWaitTimeoutException`. [Documentation here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/transactions.html#error-handling)

I recommend catching these exceptions (according to your version) and not a general one.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I am dealing with retrying failed transactions with Sf2.7 and doctrine 2.4.7:

```
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class Foo
{
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $doctrine;

    public function __construct(Registry $registry)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $registry;
    }

    protected function doSomething($entity, $attempt)
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $conn = $em->getConnection();
        try{
            $conn->beginTransaction();
            $entity->setBar("baz");
            $em->flush();
            $conn->commit();
        } catch(\PDOException $e){
            $conn->rollBack();
            $attempt++;
            if($attempt <= 3){
                $this->doSomething($repayment, $attempt);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return EntityManager
     */
    protected function getEntityManager()
    {
        /** @var EntityManager $em */
        $em = $this->doctrine->getManager();
        if(!$em->isOpen()){
            $this->doctrine->resetManager();
            $em = $this->doctrine->getManager();
        }

        return $em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Retry transaction snippet

- There's no mess about getting connection.
- While loop is properly handled

### Code

```
$connection = ...
$retry = 0;
$maxRetries = 3;

while ($retry < $maxRetries) {
    try {
        $connection->beginTransaction();

        // do stuff

        $connection->commit();

        break;
    } catch (Throwable $exception) {
        $connection->rollBack();

        $retry++;

        if ($retry === $maxRetries) {
            throw $exception;
        }
    }
}
```

More about Doctrine transactions can be found at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.7/reference/transactions.html

### How to get connection:

Simply inject Doctrine's `EntityManager` (`Interface`) or `Connection` eg. via constructor

**Connection**

```
public function __construct(Connection $connection)
{
    $this->connection = $connection;
}
```

**Or EntityManager**

```
public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}
```

And get connection as `$this->entityManager->getConnection()`

Answer (score -5):

If you are not using ORM then use that it will automatically managed deadlock situation.

Comment: I am not using ORM for insertions. Can you explain how are deadlock handled automatically?

Comment: Rorchackh, if both tables have foreign keys referencing each other, one of them cannot be NOT NULL. If everything is mapped correctly, doctrine will always persist the table with the nullable constraint, persist the one with the obligatory constraint *and* edit the first to set the correct FK value.

Comment: Doctrine *is* an ORM, and it *doesnt* handle the deadlock situation automatically. It crashes and burns with the first database error and is not easily recoverable. The problem with using an ORM is that you are effectively outsourcing the problem somewhere else, and when that somewhere else goes wrong, it can be a massive pain in the neck to fix. That's the price you pay for using an off-the-shelf ORM.