# Multiple processes updating same rows results in deadlock in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, fork, deadlock, mariadb

I'm working on a php program that forks itself several times, resulting in several worker processes which then autonomously work off a table of tasks. Each process opens it's own mysql connection (this is a must because of php's forking architecture) and should then work on it's own task (no two workers should work on the same task). For this, the workers "take" a task before starting to process it. This is achieved as follows:

1. Worker requests a task
2. A transaction is started in which all "pending" tasks are queried
3. These tasks are iterated. Script then tries to "take" each task by updating it's status. The update has a condition `where status = 'pending'` to ensure it hasn't been taken in the meantime.
4. As soon a task is sucessfully "taken", iteration stops and transaction is committed.

I tested this scenario in the mysql shell first - made two connections to the database in two terminal windows. Started a transaction in both. Then updated a task to "taken" in first window. Tried updating the same task in the second window. The second window then waited until I commited the transaction in the first window and just failed politely (0 rows affected).

Now, in php (with PDO), as soon as a second process tries to take a task, I get a deadlock on the db:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction' in ...

I'm not sure if I should only wrap the actual *updating the task to taken* in a transaction. But in my opinon, the way I'm doing it in the program is the same constellation I did it on the shell and thus should work.

Can someone help me with what I'm missing here?

Comment: what is the type of your task table : 'MyISAM' or 'InnoDB' ? in your case 'InnoDB' must be set

Comment: Deadlocks aren't something to be afraid of, they're normal. The usual way of dealing with this type of problem is to restart the transaction. You can keep track of how many times you failed due to  the deadlock and simply stop trying. The task will be incomplete and another worker will pick it up eventually.

Comment: @N.B.: you mean it's basically mysql saying "hey, another process already updated this row since you started the transaction"?. How would I restart the transaction?

Comment: @HalayemAnis: It's InnoDB yeah.

Comment: I would have thought that a deadlock would be rare as long as: you use transactions and access the resources (tables) in the same order in the 'worker tasks'. You may get 'timeouts'.

Comment: @RyanVincent that's what I would expect too, and that's what the mysql shell did - it just waited for the other transaction to finish. How would I access the ressources in the same order? Just order the tasks that I query?

Comment: In your scenario where you have workers pulling seemingly different tasks, a deadlock should be rare. This might indicate an error in your code. What happens is that N processes are trying to acquire a lock for the same row, or a similar internal error where resources are shared between concurrent processes. MySQL correctly detects this and it will deny one process or all of them from doing anything. The PHP process which issued a transaction that ended up in a deadlock should deal with it - either by restarting transaction or abandoning it.

Comment: It should get rare as soon as the job has been running for a while, but when the daemon is started all worker processes try to obtain a task right away and of course all go for the first task in the stack. My goal is that the first process gets the task and all the others that try to "take" it just fail silently (0 rows affected) and keep trying until they succeed. From then on this should not happen too often as every task will take a variable amount of time to process.

Comment: This is a classic pipeline pattern, and if I were you I'd solve it in a different way. I'd have a master process that pulls tasks and worker processes that are given one if it exists (you push a task to the worker). You'd have one entry point (master process that pulls from MySQL) and many workers. Once the worker is done, it could update MySQL on its own or it could return the result to the master process (or another process designated for updating).

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. That was pretty much the way I had it set up at first, but after getting feedback I decided to keep the task manager very simple without any business logic in a unix "do one thing well" kind of way.

Answer (score 0):

You're in InnoDB so that's good.

Are your tasks in a table? I think they are, but you didn't say so explicitly.

Try this discipline for grabbing a task on which to work.

```
BEGIN;   /* start a transaction */
SELECT task_id, whatever
  FROM tasktable
 WHERE status = 'pending'
 LIMIT 1
FOR UPDATE;
```

Then, if you get a row with a task ID back, you are ready to process that task. If you get no rows back, there aren't any pending tasks.

Mark the task as working.

```
UPDATE tasktable 
   SET status = 'working' 
 WHERE task_id = <<the task ID you just got back>>;
```

Then,

```
COMMIT;
```

If you get a deadlock exception (you might still get one, but it will be rarer) then issue `ROLLBACK;`, then try the whole sequence again.

Then, do the task. When it's done mark it as completed. You don't need a transaction for that because you can do it in one query.

```
UPDATE tasktable 
   SET status = 'complete' 
 WHERE task_id = <<the task ID you just got back>>;
```

If you have autocommit turned off in your client connection, don't forget to commit after that query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is pretty much what I'm doing and having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

I found a ["solution" that I'm going with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13150683/682583). If anyone has a different solution, I'm open to hearing it and will happily accept your answer if I end up using it.

So basically trying to "take" a task in a loop, when I get a deadlock I rollback and try again. My first tests are showing that it solves the initial problem when all workers try to get a task.