# Integration test that intentionally creates a deadlock (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, phpunit, deadlock

I'm trying to test a class `MyConnection` I've created that extends `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection` and handles deadlock cases (or lock waits) by releasing any deadlocks and resolving them. 
Therefore I need to create a deadlock on my test, in order to confirm that it works as it should. 
The idea is to create a temporary table in the database, and try to access it in two connections at once.

The challenge is that I need to do this without using multiple threads. (threads in php are created with [pthreads](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads) that needs PHP7.2+ and I have 7.1, and it's not an option to upgrade for now)

What I've already tried is using multiple connections on the database. However this created a lock wait instead. The problems with the lock wait were that:
1. it makes the integration test too slow
2. I can't delete the temporary table I create on my test. Even though the test runs on a test database, it's good practice to clean up after your tests

I have also tried forking my process. The problems with that were
1. it still creates a lock wait instead 
2. I had to exit the child process, and have the parent handling everything and making assertions. But since the deadlock happens in the child, I can't catch the errors thrown from the child through the parent

The idea in the code below is that when my `executeQuery` fails to handle the dead lock, it won't be able to write `'I am handling the deadlock or the lock wait'` in the logger, therefore I put that `shouldReceive('critical')` that will throw an error when things don't work out. Otherwise the test should pass

Class extending `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection`

```php
class MyConnection extends Connection
{
  public function executeQuery($query, array $params = [], $types = [], QueryCacheProfile $qcp = null)
  {
    try {
      $result = parent::executeQuery($query, $params, $types, $qcp);
    } catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $exception ) {
      $this->logger->critical('I am handling the deadlock or the lock wait');
    }
  }
}
```

Integration Test

```php
class DeadlockCreationTest extends Test
{
  const SERIALIZE_TRANSACTION = 'SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;';
  const START_TRANSACTION = 'START TRANSACTION;';
  const SELECT_QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM %s.innodb_deadlock_maker WHERE a = %d;';
  const UPDATE_QUERY = 'UPDATE %s.innodb_deadlock_maker SET a=%d WHERE a <> %d';

  public function setUp()
  {
    parent::setUp();
    $this->currentDbConnection = $this->getConnection();
    $this->newDbConnection = $this->getNewIdenticalDBConnection($this->currentDbConnection);
    $this->logger = Mockery::mock(Logger::class);
    $this->currentDbConnection->executeQuery(
      'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' . $this->dbName .
      '.innodb_deadlock_maker(b INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, a INT NOT NULL) engine=innodb;'
    );

    $this->currentDbConnection->executeQuery(
      'insert into ' . $this->dbName . '.innodb_deadlock_maker(a) values(0), (1);'
    );
  }

  public function testCreateDeadlock()
  {
    $pid = pcntl_fork();

    if ($pid === -1) {
      $this->fail('Could not fork child process');
    }

    if ($pid === 0) {
      $this->process = 'child';
      // In child process

      try {
        $this->logger->shouldReceive('critical')
          ->with(
            'I am handling the deadlock or the lock wait'
          );
        $this->newDbConnection->setLogger($this->logger);

        $this->newDbConnection->executeQuery(self::SERIALIZE_TRANSACTION);
        $this->newDbConnection->executeQuery(self::START_TRANSACTION);
        $this->newDbConnection->executeQuery(sprintf(self::SELECT_QUERY, $this->dbName, 1));
        $this->newDbConnection->executeUpdate(sprintf(self::UPDATE_QUERY, $this->dbName, 1, 1));
      } catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $exception) {
        if (stripos($exception->getMessage(), 'try restarting transaction') !== false) {
          exit(123);
        }
        exit(100); // Our exit code to indicate a different error occurred
      }
      exit(0); // Our exit code to indicate no error occurred
    }
    $this->process = 'parent';

    // Otherwise in parent process:

    $this->currentDbConnection->executeQuery(self::SERIALIZE_TRANSACTION);
    $this->currentDbConnection->executeQuery(self::START_TRANSACTION);
    $this->currentDbConnection->executeQuery(sprintf(self::SELECT_QUERY, $this->dbName, 0));
    $this->currentDbConnection->executeUpdate(sprintf(self::UPDATE_QUERY, $this->dbName, 0, 0));

    pcntl_waitpid($pid, $status); // Wait for forked child to exit
    $childExitCode = pcntl_wexitstatus($status);

    switch ($childExitCode) {
      case 0:
        echo "\nNo error occurred, or deadlock occurred in child but was handled correctly - success!\n";
        break;
      case 100:
        $this->fail('A different error occurred');
        break;
      case 123:
        $this->fail('Deadlock occurred in child and was not handled correctly');
        break;
      default:
        $this->fail('Child exited with unexpected exit code');
    }
  }

  public function tearDown()
  {
    $this->newDbConnection->executeQuery('DROP TABLE ' . $this->dbName . '.innodb_deadlock_maker;');
    $this->newDbConnection->close();
    parent::tearDown();
  }
}
```

What I need is ideally to create a deadlock instead of a lock wait. 
Also I need to somehow confirm that my Connection class worked as it should. 
Another issue I have with the code above is that I get the error message `PDO::exec(): MySQL server has gone away` and I don't know if and how can I stop that.

PS: The idea of the test is based on [this article](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/08/how-to-deliberately-cause-a-deadlock-in-mysql/)

Comment: Have you tried the [An InnoDB Deadlock Example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlock-example.html) from the manual? Otherwise, we would need to see the actual queries. Most waits can be turned into deadlocks.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't realise I hadn't put the actual queries on the code above. 
No I haven't tried the queries on the links you sent, I'll check them now, thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that `DBALException` catches all Exceptions.. Looking in the manual i think you need to use `RetryableException` ->  https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/transactions.html#error-handling

Comment: I've seen that when a deadlock is created a `DBALException` is thrown:
`Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: "An exception occurred while executing ...
SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction` Maybe `RetryableException` is in a future version, based on what I see, it's not in the Doctrine I currently use `"doctrine/dbal": "~2.5.0"`

Comment: Yes there is also a `DeadlockException`.. but i didn't work with Doctrine for a while ... But if you do `var_dump($exception->getMessage())` what do you get?

Comment: *" it's not in the Doctrine I currently use "doctrine/dbal": "~2.5.0""*  Consider upgrading as that version is no longer maintained

Comment: By the way also check out this [How to retry transaction after a deadlock using Doctrine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069315/how-to-retry-transaction-after-a-deadlock-using-doctrine)

Comment: Yes Raymond, that's basically what I do (I haven't put the full code of `MyConnection` here). My concern is not the implementation of the `MyConnection` class, but the test

Comment: And you're right about upgrading doctrine Raymond

Comment: I cannot write an answer (I cannot testrun your code, I can just tell you the sql part of it, feel free to self-answer if you get it to works), but to prevent that you won't get a solution: your queries lock in the first select, so you don't get a deadlock. Try the example from the manual, or e.g this: A: update pk 1 B: update pk 2; A: update pk 2 (wait for B) B: update pk 1 (deadlock). (pk = primary key, or anything indexed). It is important that the 3rd step happens after the 2nd, e.g. by adding a sleep/loop/... between the two updates to wait for the other thread to run its first update.